# DIV overlapping issue on MaterializeCSS and multilevel jQuery menu

Tags: html, css, css-float, materialize

I'm developing a tiny web app using MaterializeCSS as HTML5/CSS3 Framework. I want to add a responsivve multilevel menu on my app.

This is the responsive multilevel menu: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/19/responsive-multi-level-menu/

This is my page: http://f4lk.net46.net/starter-template/

Basically I took the Materialize starter template, I deleted some divs and the I have added the multilevel menu code. It looks horrible, overlapped, out of place.

[image]

I have hours trying to figure this out and I do not get it, can some CSS Ninja give me some advice?

Comment: It's working flawlessly on my side, could you clarify more on what you mean by "overlapped"?

Comment: @AliAbdelfattah it works, but it looks overlapped, please check the edited question, I have added a picture.

Comment: it's *above* the orange footer!

Comment: Do you want to allocate vertical space for the menu so that it pushes the footer down?

Comment: @AliAbdelfattah the divs seems to be outside of his parent, and yes, I need to push down the footer, the div seems in another layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `float` problem.

I looked at your code and I noticed a couple things that are affecting this, but the two biggest problems are where your footer is located and the float clear not being present.

Basically your menu element has a float property, that is not cleared for the next element, so other things are just going under it.

The most current way to fix this is adding the `clearfix` css property.

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
 content: "";
 display: table;
 }

.clearfix:after {
 clear: both;
 }

.clearfix {
 zoom: 1; /* ie 6/7 */
}
```

You add this to a stylesheet (your style.css one) and add that to your wrapper `div`. In this case:

```
 <div id='dl-menu' class='dl-menuwrapper clearfix'>
```

And that will make sure you don't have the overlap.

The SECOND problem that I see is that your footer isn't actually acting like a footer. It's al the way up at the top and isn't at the bottom, or footer of your page.

You can fix THAT in your `materialize.css` file by modifying the `footer.page-footer.

Change it from

```
footer.page-footer {
margin-top: 20px;
padding-top: 20px;
background-color: #ee6e73;
}
```

to

```
footer.page-footer {
margin-top: 20px;
padding-top: 20px;
background-color: #ee6e73;
/*ADD THESE LINES*/
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

And that will put your footer at the bottom of the page, 100% width of the browser.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I did what you told me, the footer was fixed, but the menu is still in the same place, although it is now under the footer, please look the code: http://f4lk.net46.net/starter-template/ I put the styles temporaly in the `<head>` in a `<style>` tag. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: The footer must be at bottom but not fixed, I should not always view the footer when I'm scrolling :(

Comment: Did you try to remove the fixed positioning?

Answer (score 1):

The menu which you're referencing is designed to flow over other items. If you want to change that behavior, start by removing the absolute positioning on the ul element to get the menu back to the normal flow.

```
.dl-menu {
 /*position: absolute;*/
}
```

The animation won't be the same, again, the menu is not designed for that, but you can start from there.